# ExtJS4 - Ext.dom.Element and fireEvent

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I'm testing ExtJS4, but need some help here...

I have this HTML code:

```
<input type="button" value="Click" id="sendButton">

<input type="text" id="tbox">
```

And this script code:

```
Ext.addBehaviors({
    '#sendButton@click': function (){
        alert("Test");
    }
}); 


Ext.get('tbox').on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == Ext.EventObject.ENTER){
        //Ext.select('#sendButton').fireEvent('click');
        //Ext.get('sendButton').fireEvent('click');
        // this is what I need working....
    }
});
```

I just want to, when you press enter on a textbox, it will act like you clicked the button.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Ext.get('tbox').on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == Ext.EventObject.ENTER){
        Ext.get('sendButton').dom.click();

    }
});
```

Though i'd suggets wrapping the above code with `Ext.onReady(function(){...})`